# java prinitng barcodes dev env issue

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

This is something very specific and hard to look up but maybe someone out there has had this issue or has some directions to point me into figuring this issue out.

So I have a java application(1.6) that will print out some data that includes a barcode that will be scanned at some point back into the system. In prod this has always worked and never been an issue. But in my local computer for some reason this barcode comes out slightly smaller and cannot be scanned at all. Any ideas?

I have tried copying and pasting the prod server's barcode format onto my local, different versions of java(1.6, 1.7, and 1.8), reformatting the barcode to replicate the prod size. All yield the same results, prod is fine. I'd like to figure this out so I can have testing be smoother for myself and not assume the barcodes work before throwing it into prod(but it always works).

```
g.setFont(new Font("AdvC39d", Font.PLAIN, 30));
g.drawString("*j" + Format.convertForBarCode1(""+ps.getJobId()) + "v" + Format.convertForBarCode2(""+ps.getVersionId()) + "*", 195, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

The description is vague, thus we can only guess...

Ensure that your app .jar file(s):

1. Have the same MD5 hashcode(s) as in the production
2. Launched with the same environment variables and program arguments (-D) (and other configuration related to your app like *.xml, *.json, *.yml, *.properties, etc.)
3. Launched on the same JVM version and build

Comment: So in this java servlet struts application we have the system auto generate/print a file based on scanning. This newer physical page will have another barcode to scan this item into the system. For a long time this barcode, if printed from my local environment, for whatever reason cannot be scanned and that is what I am trying to figure out. Previously I just manually enter the barcode values to by pass scanning to ensure it is working but finally got so annoyed that I am now posting this question.

Comment: I will check this MD5 hascodes but 2 and 3 have already been done and this has not been issue. My strong belief is something being caused by my local computer or maybe even the ide settings that i am unaware of.

Comment: The hashcodes are not an issue, don't see any code setting that up in anyway. I also added the code where you can see we set the font to the barcode to AdvC39d. This lives on prod and on my local, these both print for both environments, but on my local its a bits smaller and the scan does not work.